# Geolocation - how to display lat/lon in a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, geolocation

Having some weird problems here, and I'm completely unsure what it is.

Basically I've got two textboxes, lblLat and lblLon. I want these to display the latitude and longitude, retrieved using a geolocation. Code for all this is:

```
<asp:Textbox ID="lblLat" runat="server" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Black" Width="50px">Unknown</asp:Textbox>
        <asp:Textbox ID="lblLon" runat="server" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Black" Width="50px">Unknown</asp:Textbox>

<button id="btnLocate" onclick="GetLocation()" style="width: 15%">Loc</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function GetLocation()
            {
                if (navigator.geolocation)
                {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ShowPosition, ShowError, { maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 45000 });
                }
                else { alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser."); }
            }
            function ShowPosition(position)
            {
                //document.getElementById('<%=lblLat.ClientID %>').value = position.coords.latitude;
                //document.getElementById('<%=lblLon.ClientID %>').value = position.coords.longitude;
                var latlondata = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
                alert(latlondata);
                document.getElementById('<%=lblLat.ClientID %>').value = "Me";
                document.getElementById('<%=lblLon.ClientID %>').value = "Me";
            }
            function ShowError(error)
            {
                if (error.code == 1)
                {
                    alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                }
                else if (error.code == 2)
                {
                    alert("Location information is unavailable.");
                }
                else if (error.code == 3)
                {
                    alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                }
            }

        </script>
```

Now, here I've got it so that the latitude and longitude is retrieved and displayed in the latlondata, and it's subsequent alert.

However, I can't get the two labels to show the location. Obviously in the example above they show "Me" (which they do, but only EVENTUALLY) but even with the "Me" lines not there and the lines setting them to the latitude and longitude not commented out, they still read their initial value of "unknown".

Answer (score 0):

may try using 
 document.getElementById('<%=lblLat.ClientID %>').**innerHTML** instead of
document.getElementById('<%=lblLat.ClientID %>').value

Comment: Strange. I think this is probably the way to go but I've tried innerHTML and innerText and still they're not changing to the latitude and longitude.